# Regular expression to match speaker1: a \n speaker1: b → speaker1: a b

Tags: regex

This was my initial attempt

```
^(speaker1|speaker2): (.*?)[\n\s\r]+\k<1>:
```

But it doesn't work in this kind of cases:

speaker1: kskdjsk
speaker2: 223
speaker1: fkjfdsj

because the regex (.*?) continue to look until it finds the 3rd line.

So I tried adding a negative lookbehind (?<!^(Io|Lei):)

```
^(speaker1|speaker2): (.*?(?<!^(speaker1|speaker2):))[\n\s\r]+\k<1>:
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check at *each character position* whether there is *not* a match with a speaker pattern:

```
\bspeaker[12]:((?:(?!\bspeaker[12]).)*)
```

Having said that, if your programming environment allows for it, it will be more efficient to match only `speaker[12]:` and *split* the input text by the matches.

Comment: @really nice idea the split! but I will lose the speaker[12] part by splitting?